# Javascript API not working for Carbon Fields?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, carbon-fields

```
$(document).on('carbonFields.apiLoaded', function(e, api) {
    // Get the current value in the 'crb_text' field
    var value = api.getFieldValue( 'crb_text' );
    console.log(value);
});
```

As mentioned in the doc https://carbonfields.net/docs/advanced-topics-javascript-api/
I tried the following code but it does not work. The apiLoaded event is not triggering. Any idea why?

jQuery is loaded. I do not get any errors. But it is not working either.

Comment: Maybe your code is running before CarbonFields is loaded? Hard to say with only that much code you shared. Try creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it with us so we can try it out.

Comment: @cabrerahector my code is running in the footer and in the doc, that is all they mention. I saw some people having the same issues as me.